# Вместо авторских символов на сайте отображаются квадраты

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

Практикуюсь писать одностраничник, дошёл до раздела, где нужно использовать авторские символы:
[image: Авторский символ] 
Сначала думал, что это png картинка, но потом выяснилось, что это именно символ. Загрузил этот шрифт, подключил через @font-face, попытался вставить в unicode формате (&# 58914;) в html документ - выдаёт  
Что сделать, чтобы символы отображались, как на картинке?
P.S. Шрифт - Pe icon 7 stroke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверь, задан ли шрифт в css к данному полю... потому что это значёк отсутствия символа... если речь про font awesome.... или свой шрифт с иконками ,тогда юникод вставляется в псевдоэлемент before....или через тег i

Answer (score 0):

Всегда объявить кодировку документа с помощью meta элемента с charset атрибутом, или с использованием http-equiv и content атрибутов (называется директивой Прагма). Объявление должно полностью уместиться в первые 1024 байта в начале файла, поэтому лучше всего поместить его сразу после открывающего head тега.больше тут
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations